# User variables in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

Currently I have to import a number of files with similar names from the same path. Is there a way to store a user variable in the console session to subsequently use it in other commands?

Imagine something like:

```
g.gisenv set="thePath=/path/to/my/files/"
r.gdal.in input=thePath+rast1.tif output=rast1
```

I use [g.gisenv](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/g.gisenv.html) here only as an illustration. I am looking for something similar for user variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple answer

On Linux this is relatively easy to do using the [shell variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) available in tools like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). It goes something like:

```
myPath="/path/to/my/files/"
r.gdal.in input=$thePath"rast1.tif" output=rast1
```

Note the `""` around the file name, they are needed to concatenate the file name with the path variable.

A system agnostic solution does not seem to exist, it depends on the shell tool in use. Relaying this on system tools is in many ways a smart choice from GRASS.

### Variables in loops

I use use bash version 4.3.48, which also allows [loops](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/), for instance, to process multiple files. However loops in bash work in a diverse manner to that [suggested by Misha](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/286081/21532). Here is an example to import all the GeoTIFF files in some directory:

```
myPath="/path/to/my/files/"

for rast in ${myPath}*.tif 
do
  out=$(basename $rast .tif)
  r.in.gdal input=$rast output=$out --overwrite
done
```

Another example, this time exporting the results of some processing step. Note again how the file names of the output GeoTIFFs are concatenated:

```
myPath="/path/to/my/files/"
suff="_done.tif"

for rast in ${myPath}*.tif 
do
  in=$(basename $rast .tif)
  r.in.gdal input=$rast output=$new --overwrite
  in=$(basename $f .tif)
  [some processing]
  r.out.gdal input=$IN output="$myPath$in$suff" format=GTiff --overwrite
done
```

More about [basename](https://ss64.com/bash/basename.html) and [obtaining command outputs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/) in bash.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do this as follows:

```
MYPATH="/path/to/my/files"    
for f in ${MYPATH}/*.tif: do
  NEW=${basename "$f" .tif}
  r.in.gdal input=$f output=${NEW}
done
```

The bash builtin command `basename <file> .ext` gives you the file name without the extension. That will then become the name for the imported raster.
Just a few notes:

- You might want to add a line to convert names to lower case
- Watch out for spaces in the original tiff names

Both of these can be handled with `tr` and/or `sed` commands. For example continuting the example above, you can add before the `r.in.gdal` command:

```
   NEW_NAME=${echo $NEW | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | sed 's/ /_/'}
```

That replaces spaces with "_" and coverts UPPER to lower. Now you use the $NEW_NAME variable in the `r.in.gdal` command for the output raster name.

Comment: This code fails with the following error message: `syntax error near unexpected token `NEW=${basename "$f" .tif}'`

Comment: Try instead:  `NEW=\`basename "$f" .tif\`` using the backtick character to get the output of the `basename` command